# swagger-ui in docker serving local yaml file only displays the default petstore example project

Tags: docker, swagger-ui

I'm trying to run locally in a docker the swagger-ui and have it consume my swagger.yaml file.
Swagger file is placed here `${pwd}/foo/swagger.yaml`

What I have tried is running this command but I only get up the default `petstore` example never my local swagger file

here is the docker command

> docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v `pwd`:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui

Answer (score 2):

Slight mistake in your command.

Try to run **pwd** command in folder where your swagger.config is located. It will return the absolute path to that directory, use that path in **-v** argument instead of **pwd**

For example : If your **swagger.config** is in your home folder, the path would be

**/home/your_username** ( In my case /home/aditya )

Modify your command to use that path. In my case,

```
docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.json -v /home/aditya:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

> It is higly recommended to use ABSOLUTE PATHS while mapping volumes in
>   docker.