# Docker command for swaggerapi/swaggerui

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui

I've been trying to locally run swagger-ui with filenamed `swagger.yaml` but when I run the `docker compose up` command I'm getting the error `not found`.

Absolute Path: /home/adityamishra/my_project/swagger.yaml

Tried the following:

1. Using docker command with *Absolute Path*

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    hostname: swagger-ui
    command:
      - docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.yaml -v /home/adityamishra/my_project:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

2. Using docker command with /

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    hostname: swagger-ui
    command:
      - docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.yaml -v /:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

3. Using docker command with blank

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    hostname: swagger-ui
    command:
      - docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.yaml -v :/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

4. Without using docker command

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    hostname: swagger-ui
    ports:
     - "8085:8080"
    SWAGGER_JSON: swagger.json
```

*Project file structure:*

```
 .
 ├── docker-compose.yml
 ├── swagger.yaml
```

Note: When I try to run the swagger docker command from `/home/adityamishra` it works. The command
is `docker run -p 8085:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/swagger.yaml -v /home/adityamishra/my_project:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui`

I've looked through the following:

1. https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SwaggerHub-Questions/Host-swagger-API-documentation-on-my-own-server/td-p/141523
2. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5383
3. [swagger-ui in docker serving local yaml file only displays the default petstore example project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465770/swagger-ui-in-docker-serving-local-yaml-file-only-displays-the-default-petstore)

No luck!!!

Any help is much appriciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the volume mounting and specifying the correct path for your YAML file. Here's an updated version of your docker-compose.yml file that should work:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui:latest
    hostname: swagger-ui
    ports:
      - "8085:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/adityamishra/my_project/swagger.yaml:/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.yaml
    environment:
      - SWAGGER_JSON=/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.yaml
```

Comment: Got error: Exited with code 1. 

Reason: ` cp: '/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.yaml' and '/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.yaml' are the same file
`

Comment: Try `/usr/share/nginx/html/my_swagger.yaml` instead of `/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.yaml.`

Comment: Changed `/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.yaml` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/my_swagger.yaml`. Both in volume and environment. Same error.